# PHP: What is the Best Way To Search Through Values?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm not sure what the best way and quickest way to search through values.

I have a check list of up to 20 ids that look like the example below. But they can be stored as an array too.

```
'6e0ed0ff736613fdfed1c77dc02286cbd24a44f9','194809ba8609de16d9d8608482b988541ba0c971','e1d612b5e6d2bf4c30aac4c9d2f66ebc3b4c5d96'....
```

What i do next is get another set of items from a json api call as a php stdclass. When i loop through those items I add html for each item to display back on my website. If one of the item's id matches the ids in the checklist then i would add different html

I'm doing all this in an ajax call so what is the best and most efficient way to search through that checklist?

for example

```
    //get a list of ids from DB and store in $checklist

$checklist;

$data = file_get_contents($url);
    $result = json_decode($data, true);

foreach ( $result->results as $items )
    {
        $name = $items->name;
        $category = $items->category;
        $description = $items->description;
        $id = $items->id;

        // if ID is in $checklist then use blue background.
        $displayhtml .="<div style=\"background-color: white;\">";  
        $displayhtml .="<h3>".$name."</h3>";
        $displayhtml .="<p>".$description."</p>";
        $displayhtml .="</div>";

    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: What have you done so far? In which problem did you run? Is it JS or PHP? Please share your code.

Comment: "But they can be stored as an array too."?? If that example is not an array then what is it?

Comment: @yi_h I get the IDs from another source and then store them in the database.  So they were only stored as a string so i can easily add them to the insert sql query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple way (if you're using PHP to do this) is to use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
$checklist = array(
    '6e0ed0ff736613fdfed1c77dc02286cbd24a44f9',
    '194809ba8609de16d9d8608482b988541ba0c971',
    'e1d612b5e6d2bf4c30aac4c9d2f66ebc3b4c5d96',
    'etc.'
);
foreach ($items as $id) // $items are a similar array of ids you're checking
{
    if ( ! in_array($id, $checklist))
    {
        // not in the checklist!
    }
}
```

### Per your example:

```
foreach ( $result->results as $items )
{
    $name = $items->name;
    $category = $items->category;
    $description = $items->description;
    $id = $items->id;

    // if ID is in $checklist then use blue background.
    if (in_array($id, $checklist))
    {
        $bg = 'blue';
    }
    else
    {
        $bg = 'white'
    }
    $displayhtml .='<div style="background-color: '.$bg.';">'; 
    $displayhtml .="<h3>".$name."</h3>";
    $displayhtml .="<p>".$description."</p>";
    $displayhtml .="</div>";

}
```

There are more elegant ways to handle this, but you didn't ask for a rewrite. Personally, for starters I would add a css class instead of inlined style, but hopefully this gets you moving forward.

Comment: Compare with var_dump(array_intersect($checklist, $items));
That might be better

Comment: `var_dump()`?? Anyways, see my comment on the other answer. It depends on what OP needs to do, if he needs to handle each "not found" id separately a loop is usually easier.

Comment: Thanks i'm going to try this.   If my ids are stored as a string can i use it like this? $checklist = array( $idstring ); ?

Comment: @wesley - i need to handle each "found" separately.  The html will be different for found items

Comment: @vpets: Then you can use `array_intersect()` to return an array of "found", or remove the `!` before `in_array()` using the loop (`// IS in the checklist!`), or just use an `else` block with the loop. Check out the docs on `array_intersect()` return values - you asked "What is the best..." without providing enough context.

Comment: +1 I don't really agree with the overall code but the in_array() function is the best option in this case.

Comment: @jordan i'm a beginner so this is all i could piece together.  I'm sure my code is horrible

Comment: @vpets: I've seen much much much worse, I was just being defensive. I didn't want the example to suggest that I personally couldn't think of a better or more elegant way to handle the big picture, and to avoid comments like the one above from other users. This is totally fine and easy to understand, don't worry - just do what works for you and keep learning and getting better. Try to separate your PHP and HTML logic as much as possible.

Comment: I can't figure out how to store the ids in the array properly $i=0; while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
 $ids = $row['placeid'];
 $checklist = array([$i]=>$ids);
 $i++;
}

Answer (score 3):

I would create 2 arrays from both sets and use array_intersect() to extract overlapping ids

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

```
$array1 = array(123,234,345,456,567);
$array2 = array(321,432,345,786,874);
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);

// Results in: $result = array( 345 )
```

Comment: +1 `array_intersect()` is very cool too, I thought of posting it. A `foreach` loop does allow you to handle errors for each id not found separately however, not sure if OP needs to (I personally would favor it). Glad someone else thought of this.

Comment: The second list of items i need to handle the check one by one because when i go through each item i'm html to return back so the html would be different for the items that are in the check list.

Comment: ... I honestly don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @jordan - the list of items i get are from a json api call php stdclass.  When i loop through those items I add html for each item to display back on my website.   If one of the item's id matches the ids in the checklist then i would add different html.  I hope thats clearer

Comment: Ah, i understand. In that case you will need a foreach statement. But i see you have already discussed that with Wesley